# Append div class contain spesific class using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Have one problem , I have one div with dynamic class, but i want to append in that div,which contain class name "detail-news"
Example div :

```
<div class="music-detail-news">
<!--- Some Content -->
</div
```

class name music can dynamically change, but "detail-news" still there. I try with javascript , but i dont know how to append all div class contain class name "detail-news"

Here my javascript :

```
function appenddiv() {
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'append_test';
document.getElementById('music-detail-news').appendChild(div);
}
```

how to append all div class contain class name "detail-news" , not only "music-detail-news" ?

Comment: Could you use to set multiple classes? <div class="music detail-news">

Comment: `getElementById('music-detail-news')` won't work if you don't have `id="music-detail-news"` in the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` with attribute class ending with the substring `detail-news` and then `forEach` over the returned NodeList to append your div element.

Check out the [2. Selectors Overview](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview)

> **E[foo$="bar"]**
>
> *an E element whose foo attribute value ends exactly with the string bar*

```js
var detailsNews = document.querySelectorAll('div[class$="detail-news"]');

detailsNews.forEach(function(item) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'append_test';
  div.textContent = "appended div to " + item.classList;
  item.appendChild(div);
})
```

```html
<div class="music-detail-news">
<!--- Some Content -->
</div>

<div class="food-detail-news">
<!--- Some Content -->
</div>

<div class="health-detail-news">
<!--- Some Content -->
</div>
```

Comment: thanks its simple and usefull, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use querySelectorAll('div[class*=detail-news')

> Selects every **"div"** element whose class attribute value contains the
>   substring **"detail-news"**

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yzw11ok1/1/

```
function appenddiv() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div[class*="detail-news"');
  for(var k in elements){
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'append_test';
  elements[k].appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using IDs, you indeed have to use class. An ID is unique, but a class is not, so when you get elements by their classname you get more than one element. They can also have more than one class. In this example, the second div will have two classes `music-detail-news` and `detail-news`.

Assuming that you have multiple divs with this class

```
 <div id="firstdiv" class="music-detail-news">
 <!--- Some Content -->
 </div

  <div id="seconddiv" class="music-detail-news detail-news">
 <!--- Some Content -->
 </div
```

You could get all of them using `document.getElementsByClassName`.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("detail-news");
```

Now you can apply the div to each element in the array

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].appendChild(div);
 }
```

Or if you'd want to append to only the divs with class `music-detail-news`, you'd write:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("music-detail-news");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
   elements[i].appendChild(div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select using a partial class.

`document.querySelectorAll("[class$=-detail-news]");`

Will select any class that ends in "-detail-news"